# Spring state machine's JpaRepositoryState and JPA's @Entity

Tags: spring-statemachine

We are considering using **Spring State Machine** for the following use case:

One of our entities (i.e. a JPA entity from our domain model) can be in one of a number of states and we have millions such entities (and as many lines in our database).

We are considering using:

```
org.springframework.statemachine.data.jpa.JpaStateRepository
```

- Should we annotate our domain model classes with `JpaRepositoryState` and thereby create a dependency between our domain model and spring state machine?
- What would be an alternative to the above i.e. ensure that our JPA entity class is not too tightly coupled to `JpaRepositoryState`?
- What is the mapping/relationship between the state machine's `machineId` and the JPA entity's `@Id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JpaRepositoryState` really doesn't have anything to do with your domain model as it is our entity class to store machine configuration in an external repository. Specifically it is a state representation and similarly there are entity classes for transitions, actions and guards.

There's no relationship between `@id` and `machineId`. `@id` is just a field identifying row in a database, which is autogenerated if you store entities manually via spring-data. Fields `machineId` and `submachineId` are however used together so that you're able to define multiple machines in a repository and then make a substate to reference a machine similarly how in UML you can define a plain state and then define that to be a reference to a submachine.

It seems that I'm getting more and more questions related user's entity classes and how to handle those with a statemachine, like in [gh453](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/453). I don't really have an answer to this right now as Spring Statemachine was never designed to handle these specific use cases. This doesn't mean that Spring Statemachine would never handle these scenarious, we just don't have anything out of the box right now.

Also our documentation is lacking these topics which is a clear indication that we need to be better on that area.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.